# Mysql sql query to format a report

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table **`product_details`**:

```
Product_Code | Size | Quantity
-------------+------+-----------
CS01         | 10   | 15
CS01         | 11   | 25
CS01         | 12   | 35
PR01         | 40   | 50
PR01         | 41   | 60
```

I want a the following format for a report to get the total quantity group by product code (all sizes of product code):

```
Product_Code | Size       | Quantity
-------------+------------+----------------
CS01         | 10  11  12 | 75
PR01         | 40  41     | 110
```

I tried the following query but it does not give the result I want.

```
SELECT product_no, size, SUM(quantity) 
FROM product_details 
GROUP BY product_no;
```

Please help me to find the query to format the report.

Comment: Using `GROUP_CONCAT()` can help you ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`group concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
product_no, 
group_concat(size  SEPARATOR ' '),
sum(quantity) 
FROM product_details group by product_no;
```